# Jquery ajax not passing parameters to controller method in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code for calling the controller method ans passing the parameters.
The Method is getting called but values are coming null in controller method.

The same code is working fine in MVC 4 project, but in Asp.Net Core MVC it is not working.

```
var UserModel = {
  "FName": "Abc",
  "LName": "Pqr"
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:60600/Home/AddUser/',
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(UserModel),
  success: function () {
  }
});
```

```csharp
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  // GET: /<controller>/
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  // [HttpPost]
  // [AllowAnonymous]
  public IActionResult AddUser(UserModel model)
  {
    //  Add user model
    return Json("");
  }
}

public class UserModel
{
  public string FName { get; set; }
  public string LName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try just `data: UserModel,`

Answer (score 1):

you can try it like this

```
var UserModel =
{
    FName: "Abc",
    LName: "Pqr"
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddUser/',
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    data: UserModel,
    success: function () {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove JSON.stringify

```
var UserModel = {
  "FName": "Abc",
  "LName": "Pqr"
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:60600/Home/AddUser/',
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: "json",
  data: UserModel,
  success: function () {
  }
});
```